# Eclipse (esp-idf) adding new components issue

Tags: esp32, firmware, esp-idf

I recently started esp-ide with Eclipse and I successfully installed and run blink example.

I followed [this link](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#example-of-component-requirements)

after all, I got an error I don't get why it comes

```
CMake Error at C:/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/component.cmake:476 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create target "__idf_main" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static library
  created in source directory
  "C:/Users/7896/eclipse-workspace/Smart-Prob/main".  See documentation for
  policy CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  main/CMakeLists.txt:5 (idf_component_register)


CMake Error at C:/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/component.cmake:302 (message):
  Include directory 'C:/Users/7896/eclipse-workspace/Smart-Prob/main/include'
  is not a directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/esp/esp-idf/tools/cmake/component.cmake:478 (__component_add_include_dirs)
  main/CMakeLists.txt:5 (idf_component_register)
```

Comment: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#component-cmakelists-files

Comment: thanks for sharing I follow the link and https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#example-of-component-requirements

Comment: but I got an error i don't upload in comments as it is quite large alphabets

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question and add the error there.

Comment: Do you have a `main()` function in your component (other than the main component)? You're only allowed one `main()`.